# Set multiple keys having multiple values to Redis

Tags: php, caching, redis

I have a php backend using `phpredis` (a php client for the redis server) to store key value pairs to a Redis server. The data I need to store is of this form:

```
"key1" => "v1", "v2", "v3"
"key2" => "m1", "m2", "m3"
"key3" => "n1", "n2", "n3"
...
```

Based on my research, I can set multiple keys in a redis using the `mset` command like so:

```
$redis->mSet(array('key0' => 'value0', 'key1' => 'value1'));
```

But what I actually need is something like this:

```
$redis->mSet(array('key0' => array('v1','v2','v3') , 'key1' => array('m1', 'm2', 'm3')));
```

But this just stores the value for each key as "Array" instead of the actual array specified.

Is this possible to do with a single command like `mset` or do I need to iterate my data and set each key separately using something like `lPush`?

phpredis documentation: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis

Comment: @Mikey that would mean I iterate my data and at each iteration do something like:
$redis->sAdd('key1' , 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'); , yes? Or can I somehow combine this with something like mset and complete it in one operation?

Answer (score 2):

So rather than using `mSet` you can probably use `sADD` to get your desired functionality.

```
$redis->sAdd($key, ...$data);
```

Full documentation on it [here](https://redis.io/commands/sadd).

This would mean iterating and doing it in multiple steps for which I'd reccomend reading into [Redis Pipelines](https://mikey.codes/posts/redis-pipelines/) and the non-shameless plug [link](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) which contains more information.

Which would look something like;

```
$redis    = new Redis();
$pipeline = $redis->multi(Redis::PIPELINE);

foreach ($dataset as $data) {
    $pipeline->sAdd($data['key'], ...$data['values']);
}

$pipeline->exec();
```

I can't think off the top of my head a way to do this in a singular operation, someone else might come along though who knows more than me :)

---

*Edit:* Looks like I misunderstood your question a little as it was more focused on doing this in a single operation. Hopefully the above is still useful but to my knowledge you'll have to do this with multiple.